# What controller is on this t-shirt?

Tags: controllers, hardware-identification

I was looking at this ["Console General" shirt on woot](https://shirt.woot.com/offers/console-general) and I am unable to identify one of the controllers:

[image: Unidentified controller from "Console General" shirt]

(It's the last controller on the second row.)

What console is it from? None of the others are third-party controllers (well, the GunCon is a notable exception), so I don't think it's third-party. I've been through [all of the generations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_video_game_console_generations), to no avail (but perhaps I missed [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighth_generation_of_video_game_consoles)).

Comment: The shape looks like an Ouya controller, but the button layout is wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouya

Comment: @computercarguy perhaps the shape matches, but the shirt is older than the Ouya. The shirt came out in 2009

Comment: Well, this is the first time I think I've seen it. Woot doesn't say when it was designed. And looking on Amazon shows it's only been available there since 2018, so how would I know how old the design is?

Comment: @computercarguy Sorry. I didn't mean to imply that you should have known how old the shirt was. Just explaining why I don't think your suggestion is correct. It was a good suggestion. It's really close. I just don't think it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It could be this one, [NES Max](https://gamicus.fandom.com/wiki/NES_Max):

[image]

> The NES Max was a controller that was released by Nintendo for the NES in 1988.

Comment: This was a great controller for games that featured D-Pad circling like Track & Field II. Only thing better was the NES Advantage stick controller.

Answer (score 24):

That looks like an NES Max controller to me.

https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/NES_Max

[image]